# Como deixar o primeiro caractere maiúsculo no teclado?

Tags: java, android

Como fazer teclado iniciar com letra maiúscula para o usuário começar a escrever sem ter que tocar na seta para deixar a letra maiuscula?

Eu usei `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` mas não funcionou direito, porque ele escreve o texto todo em uma linha e eu não quero que isso aconteça

Comment: tenta dessa forma `android:inputType="textCapSentences"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente há duas maneiras deixar o primeiro caractere maiúsculo no teclado, via XML e programaticamente. Veja:

**XML**

Configurar seu `ExitText` desta forma usando `textCapWords|textCapSentences`:

```
android:inputType="textCapWords|textCapSentences"
```

**Programaticamente**

```
EditText editor = new EditText(this); 
editor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: Esse textCapSentences funciona sim, mas ele não quebra linha entende? Vou testar esse EditText

Comment: @Aline fiz uma alteração, inserindo `textCapWord` junto com `textCapSentences` e funcionou perfeito aqui na minha aplicação. Se houver mais alguma dúvida, chame aqui.

Comment: Deu certo aqui....